# C++ lambda function pass by reference problem

Tags: c++, function, lambda, pass-by-reference

I used a lambda function in order to store point cloud into each instance of a vector. Even I pass the vector by reference, when I try to access each instance of the vector, I get this error:

```
typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

My codes:

```
int size_ = 2;
std::vector<Cloud::Ptr> vector_cloud(size_);
for(int i=0; i<size_; i++)
{
    Cloud::Ptr cloud_(new Cloud);
    vector_cloud.push_back(cloud_);
}
auto fonk1 = [ &vector_cloud, size_]()
        {

            for(int i=0; i<size_; i++)
            {
                std::cout << "for debug" << std::endl;
                Point p;
                p.x = 0;
                p.y = 0;
                p.z = 0;
                p.intensity = 0;
                vector_cloud[i]->points.push_back(p);
            }
        };
fonk1();
std::cout << "Cloud size: " << vector_cloud[0]->size() << std::endl;
```

It's not a compiling error, and output is:

```
for debug
```

I get this error, when I try to push a point. `Cloud::Ptr` is `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::pointXYZI>::Ptr` and `Point` is `pcl::PointXYZI`

Also even I delete those lines:

```
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    Cloud::Ptr cloud(new Cloud);
    vector_cloud_frustums.push_back(cloud);
}
```

Error is the same.

Comment: what is `Cloud` and `Cloud::Ptr` ? Can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: another very interesting case of UB. Even without turning on optimizations funny things can happen. See the link in my answer, I had some fun playing around with it. Uncommenting the last line changes output that comes **before** completely

Comment: I delete the related lines, error is the same. I updated the post. Also, I have to use type of Ptr, since I work on the huge software project.

Comment: if you delete those lines then you still have 2 elements in the vector that do not point to `Cloud` instances. Wait a sec, I'll update the answer

Comment: see edited  answer

Comment: "since I work on the huge software project" I still believe that there is a misunderstanding. Having a huge project isnt a reason to store pointers in a vector, though thats a topic for a different question maybe

Comment: Okay, your last update works well. I'll accepted soon, but this my question is about passing argument by reference. Even I do not pass by reference to lambda function, vector is still updated why?

Comment: you do capture the vector by reference. If you have a quesiton about some code that does something else you can open another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `Point`, `Cloud` and `Cloud::Ptr` are something like this:

```
struct Point {
    int x,y,z,intensity;
};

struct Cloud {
    std::vector<Point> points;
    void push_back(const Point& p) { points.push_back(p);}
    using Ptr = Cloud*;
    size_t size() const { return points.size(); }
};
```

It turned out they are something else, but that doesnt matter that much for the answer.

---

The issue in your code is that you create a vector of size 2:

```
std::vector<Cloud::Ptr> vector_cloud(size_);
```

Then you push 2 more elements in this loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<size_; i++)
{
    Cloud::Ptr cloud_(new Cloud);
    vector_cloud.push_back(cloud_);
}
```

The first two elements do not point to instances of `Cloud`. Only the last two point to a `Cloud`. Then in the last line of your code:

```
std::cout << "Cloud size: " << vector_cloud[0]->size() << std::endl;
```

You dereference the first element in the vector and cause undefined behavior. You can see the effect in this [complete example](https://godbolt.org/z/5ExnrE).

Conclusion: The problem in your code is not the lambda or capturing the vector. The bad line is the last one. It invokes undefined behavior. In the above link you can uncomment that line to see how it effects what the rest of the code does (even if that other code comes before).

The fix is to either create vector with size 2 upfront and then access those element *or* use `push_back`, but not both. For example:

```
int size_ = 2;
std::vector<Cloud::Ptr> vector_cloud;  // empty vector !!
vector_cloud.reserve(size_);           // reserve space
for(int i=0; i<size_; i++)
{
    Cloud::Ptr cloud_(new Cloud);
    vector_cloud.push_back(cloud_);    // push elements
}
```

---

*PS* Very likely you do not need any pointers in the code. Use a `std::vector<Cloud>` instead of a `std::vector<Cloud*>`, unless there is a reason to introduce a level of indirection. And when there is, use smart pointers.